# "Except as being" or "except being"

Tags: prepositions

I stumbled upon a phrase on the internet the grammar of which I can't understand.

> **Except as being** a bit too conservative and Republican-Lite, don't you
>   think XXX is one of the best President?

It was written by a native speaker, so it's most likely that it's just me who can't grasp the meaning of the sentence, not a grammatical mistake in it. Why is *except as being* used here? Wouldn't *except being* be fine?

Comment: It should be "except for being"; I don't know why there's an "as" there.

Comment: So, the above-mentioned phrase is ungrammatical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with @andrewdotnich that I'd probably write either *'except for being'* or *'apart from being'* before writing *'except as being'*, it is by all means grammatical.  [This NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except+for+being%2Cexcept+as+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):
[image] shows that *except as being* was used quite frequently in the 1800's and was overtaken by "except for being" around the turn of the century.

Comment: *except as being* is grammatical, but seems to be used in other ways besides OP's sentence. Can you cite an instance where it is used as OP cites it?

Comment: @zpletan: I think a lot of the instances that show up there are used similarly to OPs usage.  I consider any usage where substitution of either "*apart from*" or "*except for*" does not change the meaning to be OP's usage. [For example](http://books.google.com/books?id=-ZLVBg1c_jwC&pg=PA27&dq=%22except+as+being%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fE2ET-aWM6Hs2QXu8OX-CA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22except%20as%20being%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase as you posted is ungrammatical. A better choice of preposition would be 'for':

"Except *for* being…"

or even better,

"*Apart from* being…"