# "can't do anything except eating" vs. "can't do anything except eat"

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives

> 1. My dog is so lazy. It can't do anything **except eating** food.
> 2. My dog is so lazy. It can't do anything **except eat** food.

Which one is right?
We asked this question in two different forums but we received different answers. Some said #1 is correct and some said #2 is correct. Look at their responses:

A selection of answers taken from [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-anything-except-blame-blaming-others.2782950/#post-17003097)

> - No. *Except* or *but* is followed by the bare infinitive here @e2efour
> - The clue is in the first part of the sentence:
>     The structure is "they could not  except .
>     I suppose, in full, it would be *They couldn't do anything except they could blame others.* @PaulQ
> - Q70. He is not interested in doing anything except **watching** movies
>     You see now? Here, "ing" is used instead of bare infinitive. I think it's because of the word "doing"
>     Am I right? (The OP @xiaoen)
> - If you say *watch*, it could mean that he avoids watching movies at all costs.
>     If you say *watching*, it means that he is only interested in watching movies. @e2efour

However, in the  [The Free Dictionary Language Forums > English Grammar](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst175041_except-eating--vs---except-eat.aspx), someone else offered the following explanation.

> - 'Except' is a preposition.
>     *My dog is so lazy. It can't do anything except **eating** food*
>     @Víctor Lplz

Now we are confused. Which one is correct, and *why*?

Thank you.

Comment: Number 2 is correct

Comment: related: 1. [“Except as being” or “except being”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63673/except-as-being-or-except-being) 2. [Case after 'except'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365333/case-after-except) 3. [“but, except, besides”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177440/but-except-besides)

Comment: "…except eat…" and please note that the "food" is redundant

Answer (score 5):

It seems the answer (in part) is found in the [modal verb](http://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-after-modals) *can*; modal verbs (*can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *shall*, *should*, *will*, and *would*) accept only bare infinitive verbs.

> **A.** My dog is so lazy. It **can't** *fetch* sticks, *chase* after a cat or even *roll over* but it **can** *eat*.
>
> 2. My dog is so lazy. It **can't** *do* anything **except** *eat*

If the OP substituted *can* with any of the preceding modal verbs, the verb that followed "except" would still be the bare infinitive.

> 3. My dog is so lazy, it **won't** do anything **except** eat.

However, if we switch the modal verb (*can*)  with a normal verb that accepts a gerund, we have the following

> My dog is so lazy, it **enjoys** nothing but **eating**.
>
> My dog is so lazy, it *enjoys* ***doing*** nothing *except* ***eating***.

The version with the bare infinitive works less well, it is less harmonious than the former but I wouldn't say it was "wrong" per se.

> My dog is so lazy, it *enjoys* ***doing*** nothing *except* ***eat***.

### Resources

There appears to be precious little on this aspect in the grammar books which I consulted at home. The advanced English grammar books tend to dismiss it entirely whereas the student-friendly books tend to repeat the same rule.

> When **except** is followed by a verb, we usually use the infinitive without *to*.
>
> I couldn't do anything **except** just **sit** there and hope.
>          She did nothing **except complain** the whole time she was here.
>   *Except* is normally followed by object-forms of personal pronouns (me, him, etc.), except in a very formal style.
>         *Everybody understood **except** me.*
>
> *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan

and in  *A Practical English Grammar* by A.J. Thomson and A.V. Martinet

> **98 B** The only exceptions to the gerund rule are **except** and **but** (preposition), which take the the bare infinitive:
>
> *I could do nothing except agree*
>         *He did nothing but complain*
>
> However, if **but** is used as a conjunction, it can be followed directly by the full infinitive or gerund:
>
> *Being idle sometimes is agreeable, but being idle all the time might become monotonous*.
>         *To be idle sometimes is agreeable, but to be be idle all the time* etc.

Comment: Maybe you meant *preceding* rather than *precedent*. But anyway, yes, the sentence seems reduced from *My dog can't do anything except it can eat*.

Comment: @Clare thanks for pointing out the error. I have been hearing "unprecedented" a hell of a lot of times of late, and I guess it's stuck in my head.